# Digital 4K acquisition vs 4k exhibition

Tags: resolution, cinema

I did some simple calculations using the classic SMPTE reference for cinema viewing AOV of 43.4 degrees, at average human visual acuity of being able to resolve lines at 1 arc minute, at obtained a result confirming that a resolution above 4k would not provide any noticeable difference. I understand this is ignoring many other factors, such as contrast, motion blur, hyper acuity and probably much more. Nevertheless, I also read that in the early 2000s Eastman Kodak performed an experiment where they determined that viewers were able to just perceive a noticeable difference at an increase from 3k to 4k.

However, as according to the Nyquist theory, to capture a 4k scenery you would need a camera with an 8k resolution.

So does that mean that when I have acquisition with 4k and exhibition at 4k I am showing a 2k representation of the scene?

What about an acquisition at 8k and displaying at 4k vs at 8k is there a difference? seeing as the acquisition would be a 4k sample of the scene.

Lastly what if I used film and projected the image on a digital projector at 4k. How would the image compare to digital, acquisition 4k exhibition 4k and acquisition 8k exhibition 4k?

Thank you for your time

Comment: The question(s) is interesting but you need to focus on what are you really asking. As it is is confusing what the question is.

Comment: I _really_ want to close this as unclear what you are asking. Because I have a strong suspicion that there will be a long comment chain under this question, and probably under answers, that will be a lot of back and forth, further questions and answers, which indicates the question is unclear. Please consider editing your question to be _clear_ about what you're asking.

Comment: To begin with, please rewrite your question's title as a single, complete sentence ending in a question mark. If you can word it that way, the rest of the question body should be easy to write to support the title question. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I was going to rephrase the question just now but saw that Steven Kerstin has provided a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, as according to the Nyquist theory, to capture a 4k scenery you would need a camera with an 8k resolution.

This is mistaken... it requires two pixels of resolution to record *one line pair* (or one cycle; min-max). Which is one pixel per line/detail.

So, no... 4k recording/display does not equate to 2k; it is 4k. And 8k source displayed at 4k instead of 8k is a 50% loss.

A scene always contains more than 4k/8k resolution; even if the details are too small for you to see unaided. Every stage in taking a picture is "lossy." A scene has immense amounts of detail possible, but a lens only resolves a small portion of that, and the sensor will fail to resolve everything the lens did (unless the lens has far less resolution than the sensor does). So the last part of the question regarding film vs digital is too theoretical to really answer; there are too many variables.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose when thinking in line pairs as you mentioned it does simplify and make it all much more intuitive.

Comment: Lines per mm and line pars per mm are the exact same thing. "Lines" count only the dark half of "line pairs", which count both the light half and the dark half as two parts of a single pair. 50 lines per mm means 50 dark lines separated by 50 light spaces. 50 line pairs per mm means 50 dark lines separated by 50 light lines. The only difference is whether the non-dark portion is counted as half of a line pair or as a space.

Comment: @MichaelC, the only place where "lines" is typically used, and count only the black lines, are OEM/optical bench MTF curve graphs. Regardless, Nyquist does not reduce a sensor's resolution to less than it has. The only requirement is that whatever two adjacent pixels are resolving be different enough to distinguish separately.